# Authenticate MVC Application with UseCookieAuthentication and an exisiting Web API OAuth Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, oauth

I have created my own web api OAuth authentication server with my customized **Microsoft.Owin** implementation:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Auth/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

Now I want to use that OAuth authentication in an external mvc application but I've been really confused.
In fact my main concern is authorizing controllers and actions based on my existing OAuth server.

After 2 days research finally I implemented that based on a custom **OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider** which is worked based on a cookie created during sign in process. The functionality works correctly  But I think (actually I know) something is wrong.
this is my Custom **OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider** :

```
public class ApplicationOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        var tokenCookie = context.OwinContext.Request.Cookies["BearerToken"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenCookie))
        {
            context.Token = tokenCookie;
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

and this is my MVC auth startup configure method:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/SignIn")
        });

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),
        });
    }
```

If someone has related experience please advise me.

---

**UPDATE: I think finally I found a solution.**

In my solution during sign in process I create a ticket and protect that inside **OAuthBearerOptions** which is defined inside **Startup.Auth** class.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn(LoginPageModel pageModel, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SignIn", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
    }

    try
    {
        var result = await AuthService.Instance.AuthenticateAsync(pageModel.LoginModel);

        CreateIdentity(result);

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SignIn", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
    }
}

private void CreateIdentity(TokenResponseModel result)
{
    IDictionary< String, String> data = new Dictionary< String, String>
    {
        { "userName", result.Username }
    };

    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, result.Username));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, result.Username));

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ExternalIdentity))
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.ExternalIdentity, result.ExternalIdentity));
    }

    if (result.Roles != null && result.Roles.Length != 0)
    {
        foreach (var role in result.Roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
    }

    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

    Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
}
```

And the **Auth Configure** is changed to this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/SignIn"),
    });

    OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
}
```

Comment: I think finally I found a solution.
In my solution during sign in process I create a ticket and protect that inside **OAuthBearerOptions** which is inside **Startup.Auth** class. I added the solution in end of my question.